# python gevent import error

Tags: python, gevent

When I run an example of gevent, I get import error here. 
I am using macos, gevent is installed by pip.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gevent
>>> from gevent import socket
>>> urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
>>> jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gevent/greenlet.py", line 201, in spawn
    g = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "gevent/greenlet.py", line 75, in __init__
    hub = get_hub()
  File "gevent/hub.py", line 169, in get_hub
    hub = _threadlocal.hub = hubtype(*args, **kwargs)
  File "gevent/hub.py", line 268, in __init__
    loop_class = _import(self.loop_class)
  File "gevent/hub.py", line 198, in _import
    return _import(path[-1])
  File "gevent/hub.py", line 210, in _import
    x = __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named core
```

===============================================================
PS:When I install gevent, there are some warnings in the output.

```
tanminghuan@bogon ~/Code/gevent (master)$ sudo pip install gevent
Downloading/unpacking gevent
  Downloading gevent-0.13.8.tar.gz (300kB): 300kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gevent

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg (from gevent)
Installing collected packages: gevent
  Running setup.py install for gevent
    building 'gevent.core' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c gevent/core.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/gevent/core.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    gevent/core.c:8113:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        __pyx_r = evbuffer_get_length(__pyx_v_self->__pyx___obj);
                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/gevent/core.o -levent -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/gevent/core.so
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libevent.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libevent.dylib
    Linking /private/tmp/pip_build_root/gevent/build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/gevent/core.so to /private/tmp/pip_build_root/gevent/gevent/core.so

Successfully installed gevent
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Are you trying to install an x86 package on an x64 machine?

Comment: @Serdalis The build is done by pip, I don't know why pip chose i386.

Comment: One more thing, in the python lib of gevent, there is core.so, I can not find core.py.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is re-installing the dependencies, or trying the 1.0 candidate for gevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the following method, now it's working well.

```
tanminghuan@bogon ~/Code $ export CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include
tanminghuan@bogon ~/Code $ sudo pip install cython "git+git://github.com/surfly/gevent.git@1.0rc3#egg=gevent"
ystem/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c c-ares/inet_ntop.c -o build/temp.maco
```